# powershell Get-ChildItem given multiple -Filters

Tags: powershell

Is there a syntax for the `-Filter` property of `Get-ChildItem` to allow you to apply multiple filters at the same time? i.e. something like the below where I want to find a few different but specific named .dll's with the use of a wildcard in both?

`Get-ChildItem -Path $myPath -Filter "MyProject.Data*.dll", "EntityFramework*.dll"`

or do I need to split this into multiple Get-ChildItem calls? because I'm looking to pipe the result of this.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The `-Filter` parameter in `Get-ChildItem` only supports a single string/condition AFAIK. Here's two ways to solve your problem:

You can use the `-Include` parameter which accepts multiple strings to match. This is slower than `-Filter` because it does the searching in the cmdlet, while `-Filter` is done on a provide-level (before the cmdlet gets the results so it can process them). However, it is easy to write and works.

```
#You have to specify a path to make -Include available, use .\* 
Get-ChildItem .\* -Include "MyProject.Data*.dll", "EntityFramework*.dll"
```

You could also use `-Filter` to get all DLLs and then filter out the ones you want in a where-statement.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.dll" .\* | Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^MyProject.Data.*|^EntityFramework.*' }
```

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that `-Include` is only successful when used with `-Recurse` like you have done in your example.

Comment: @FrodeF. I missed that since it wasnt bold, underline, italicized, and have a blinking sign that says live live code.

Comment: How to find folder that has both MyProject.Data*.dll & EntityFramework*.dll?

Comment: Try (untested): `Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.dll" -Recurse | Group-Object DirectoryName | Where-Object { ($_.Group.Name -match '^MyProject\.Data\.') -and ($_.Group.Name -match '^EntityFramework\.') } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name`

Comment: You can use `-Include` without `-Recurse` but then you need to add `\*` to the folder.
`Get-ChildItem folder\* -Include *.xml,*.json `

Comment: +1 for using `.\*` rather than `-Recurse`. OP probably didn't want to list files recursively. At least I didnt ;)

Answer (score 13):

You may join the filter results in a pipe like this:

```
@("MyProject.Data*.dll", "EntityFramework*.dll") | %{ Get-ChildItem -File $myPath -Filter $_ }
```

Comment: @NicoNekoru Why would a question being old and having old answers make it not appropriate to be answered? If anything, new answers should be _encouraged_ in old questions because technology is constantly evolving, and new more efficient ways to achieve the same results are being constantly implemented.

Comment: @stackexchange_account1111 this question brings nothing new and even is as pointed out by https://stackoverflow.com/a/30151327/12671858, a worse alternative to `-Include`. The answer itself is fine but there is no point in duplicating the other answers and providing a solution more inefficient than the currently accepted one. As discussed in [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/how-should-we-deal-with-duplicate-answers) such answers like this one are unnecessary.

Comment: Wait so is it fine or is it a duplicate? Because the two are mutually exclusive (unless posted simultaneously). More importantly though, whether this specific one is less efficient or not is irrelevant. You gave a prescriptive statement that old questions with old answers should not be answered which is an incredibly counterproductive way of thinking when it comes to technology.

Answer (score 3):

You can only use one value with `-Filter`, whereas  `-Include` can accept multiple values, for example ".dll, *.exe".

Answer (score 0):

You could use both `-Filter` and `-Include` at the same time

`Get-ChildItem -Path $myPath -Filter "*.dll" -Include "MyProject.Data*.dll", "EntityFramework*.dll"`