# Powershell how to filter Get-ChildItem with a multiple values

Tags: powershell

I need to get-children items a directory and find to a specific named  zip file.

I don't know to zip file's name. But one thing that I know the zip file includes a date. And I have to find full path of zip from that date. I mean like:

```
   xxxx_20220810.zip
   or
   xxxx20220810.zip
```

I check this topic  [powershell Get-ChildItem given multiple -Filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30150930/powershell-get-childitem-given-multiple-filters) but this page doesn't help me.

```
   $date = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMdd')
   $zipPath = Get-ChildItem  -Path $path -Filter '*.zip'  -Recurse| % { $_.FullName -match $date}
   $zipPath = Get-ChildItem  -Path $path -Filter '*.zip'  -Recurse| % { $_.FullName -contains $date}
```

Comment: `-Filter "*_${date}.zip"`

Comment: Sorry I edited the question. I'm not sure is there " _ " or something like that. I just know the name contains date. So its better if is there a option like contains.

Comment: Okay, so `-Filter "*${date}*.zip"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for can still be expressed as a single filter expression:

```
$date = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMdd')
$zipPath = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter "*${date}*.zip" -Recurse
```

---

`-Filter` only accepts a single pattern, so if you do need to filter against any of a number of conflicting patterns, you'll still have to use `Where-Object`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter *.zip -Recurse |Where-Object {
   $_.BaseName -like "*${year}*${month}*${day}*" -or $_.BaseName -like "*${year}*${day}*${month}*"
}
```

Comment: <code>$zipPath = Get-ChildItem -Path $a -Filter{"*${year}*${month}*${day}*.zip" -or "*${year}*${day}*${month}*.zip"} -Recurse   <code>   can I use something like this?

Comment: No, `-Filter` only accepts a single glob pattern, you'll need to use `Where-Object` if you want multiple comparison operations, eg `Get-ChildItem -Filter *.zip |Where-Object { $_.BaseName -like "*${year}*${month}*${day}*" -or $_.BaseName -like "*${year}*${day}*${month}*"}`